# Convert Boolean to condition in Expression tree

Tags: linq-to-sql, lambda, expression, expression-trees

Hi Experts
How I Can convert this statement to Expression tree:

```
x=>x.Contains("bla")
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "x");
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<string, bool>>(
    Expression.Call(
        parameter,
        "Contains",
        Type.EmptyTypes,
        Expression.Constant(
            "blah"
        )
    ),
    parameter
);
```